# Jquery create object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

This is a simple question I know, I've looked on google but can't find much help.  I'm trying to create an object, with my own custom parameters, and then call one of them in an alert.

Whatever I try, doesn't seem to work, I know this is pretty simple stuff and I appologise!  All my other JS in my time have been pretty simple and all inline because of that, I'm moving on to more OOP JS now.

```
$.fn.DataBar = function() {

        $.DataBar.defaultOptions = {
            class: 'DataBar',
            text: 'Enter Text Here'
        }

        this.greet = function() {
            alert(this.text);
        };
} 

var q = new $.DataBar();
q.greet();
```

Comment: What happens when you try `$.DataBar.greet = function(){` instead of `this.greet = function() {`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You don't need the `fn` part, simply use:

   ```
   $.DataBar = function () { ... };
   ```

   `$.fn` is simply a reference to jQuery's internal *prototype*. So `$.fn.DataBar` is intended to be used as `$(selector).DataBar()`, not `$.DataBar()`.
2. Your default options aren't being applied to the newly created object. Optionally, you can also define the `greet` function on `DataBar`'s prototype:

   ```
   $.DataBar = function () {
       $.extend(this, $.DataBar.defaultOptions);
   };

   $.DataBar.prototype.greet = function () {
       alert(this.text);
   };

   $.DataBar.defaultOptions = {
       class: 'DataBar',
       text: 'Enter Text Here'
   };
   ```

Comment: You described, why it isn't neccessary to bin DataBar to "fn", but why bind it to the "$" at all?

Comment: @Tim, you don't have to ;) I assumed you wanted it to be related to jQuery somehow, for namespacing or association reasons, so I kept it there.

Answer (score 2):

There are <strike>4</strike> 3 problems in your code

1. a missing `;` after the default options (not causing the error)
2. add the default options to the instance with `this.defaultOptions`
3. call `alert(this.defaultOptions.text)`
4. instantiate with `$.fn.DataBar()` as you added your class to `$.fn`

Here your code working:

```
$.fn.DataBar = function() {

        this.defaultOptions = {
            class: 'DataBar',
            text: 'Enter Text Here'
        };

        this.greet = function() {
            alert(this.defaultOptions.text);
        };
};

var q = new $.fn.DataBar();
q.greet();
```

Comment: Don't want to start a holy comment war, but aren't semicolons optional in JavaScript? I like this blog posting on this specific topic: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: You are right in this one. But you will get errors with i.e. JSLint validation as said in the article ;-). but alright, I will remove that one.

Comment: Well, there should be an option for that :-)